# Insert an auto incremented ID from Table 2 into Table 1 on insert statement MySql

Tags: mysql, insert, inner-join, mysql-workbench

I have a stored procedure in MySql, where I an trying to insert values into Person_Table.
One of the columns in Person_Table is CompanyID.

But I need to retrieve that CompanyID from `Company_Table.CompanyID` is an auto incremented Primary key. Both tables also have columns `CompanyName`.
I want to insert `Company+Table.CompanyID` into the `Person_Table.CompanyID` column in the same procedure.

I am having problems inner joining the 2 tables. ***Can*** you inner join tables on an insert statement?

This is what I have so far but it doesn't like the inner join:

```
        insert into person p
    (FarmName, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Phone, CompanyID)
    values
   ( oFarmName, oFirstName, oMiddleName, oLastName, oPhone, oCompanyID)   

    inner join company c on p.FarmNamne =  c.CompanyName
    where p.FarmName = c.CompanyID;
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer whether it is possible to insert on an inner join but my feeling says it's not possible.

Anyways, to offer a little help, I would suggest that you solve this problem differently:

How about you put a trigger on your first table `AFTER INSERT`. At this point of time the auto increment id is known and can easily be inserted in table 2 with your trigger.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: Thank you. I am ttrying to use a trigger. It's my first time using them so I don't know exactly the syntax. This is what I have so far but it is not working. `CREATE
    DEFINER =  CURRENT_USER 
    TRIGGER Assign_CompanyID 
    Before INSERT ON individual
    For each row set NEW.CompanyID = Company.CompanyID
    Where Individual.FarmName = Company.CompanyName`

Comment: This is untested but try `CREATE TRIGGER Assign_CompanyID AFTER INSERT ON individual
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO name_of_table_2 SET table_2_company_id = NEW.CompanyID, table_2_another_field = NEW.another_field;
  END;`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, then this should work after renaming the tables and columns to match your information:

```
INSERT INTO Person_Table
(FarmName, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Phone, CompanyID)
VALUES
( oFarmName, oFirstName, oMiddleName, oLastName, oPhone, (
    SELECT c.CompanyId FROM Person_Table p 
    INNER JOIN Company_Table c ON c.CompanyName = p.CompanyName)
)
```

This will only work if there are no duplicate Company Names but give it a shot.